# Java Script is not working inside the php

Tags: php, javascript

```
public function actionAjaxUpdate()
    {   
        $action = $_GET['act'];


        if(!isset($_POST['selectedId']))
        {
            echo '<script> alert("No row is selected"); </script>';
        }

        else
        {
        $selectedAll = $_POST['selectedId'];
        if(count($selectedAll)>0)
        {
            foreach($selectedAll as $selectedId)
            {
                $model=$this->loadCompositeModel($selectedId);
                switch ($action) {
                    case 'Delete':
                        $model['account']->delete();
                        break;
                    case 'Active':
                        $model['account']->active = '1';
                        break;
                    case 'Inactive':
                        $model['account']->active = '0';                     
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                $model['account']->save();
            }
        }
        }

    }
```

- List item

In this code Alert is not working, if no id is selected.So some one help me out. i have tried alot but js is not working.
I have used js inside the php and this is the first time when js is not working inside the php

Comment: Check whether your condition is correct.

Comment: please post your form, so we can see what `$_POST['selectedId']` is

Comment: hey condition is correct. i have check it on firebug @ Edwin

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code that makes the HTTP request, it is hard to say what the problem is.

Them most likely explanation that `selectedId` *is set* to an empty string when no id has been selected. The condition `!isset($_POST['selectedId'])` will then not give you the result you want. Use `empty()` instead (and make sure that `0` is not an acceptable id value).

Comment: 'columns'=>array(
  array(    
   'id'=>'selectedId',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',   
     //'value'=>'$data->user_status',
        
        ), 
  'uid',
  'username',
  'password',
  'bid',
  
  array(
            'name'=>'active',
   //'header'=>'Active',
            'filter'=>array('1'=>'Yes','0'=>'No'),
            'value'=>'($data->active=="1")?("Yes"):("No")'
        ),
  array(
   'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
  ),
 ),
)); ?>

Answer (score 0):

It seems `$_POST['selectedId']` is an array. then you should use `isset` for elements of `$_POST['selectedId']` for example `if (!isset($_POST['selectedId'][0]))`

EDIT 1: try this one

```
$array_id = array_filter($_POST['selectedId']);
```

then use  `if (!empty($array_id))` instead of `if (!isset($_POST['selectedId']))`

Comment: yes $_POST['selectedId'] is an array. But shall i know element of $_POST['selectedId']

Comment: Then you mean, you don't know elements?

Comment: no i mean when i selected a row selectedId returns the id of the row. so how can i use that id

Comment: Where does `selectedid` come from? put the code or show us what is elements of `selectedid`? perhaps something like `$_POST['selectedId']['id']`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're injecting the response back into the page, the Javascript will never be evaluated.

If you were to do...

```
document.write('<script src="/path/to/phpscript.php">')
```

then the response will be appended to the page and evaluated.

However, if you do...

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(response) {
        //Blah....  
    }
});
```

or something to that effect, the response is never evaluated, it's passed to your success function as a string. So you could just get the PHP to print `1` or `0` for success/failure - or even better return a Json object

```
<?php

    ...
    if(!isset($_POST['selectedId']))
    {
        $Ret->Success = false;
        $Ret->Reason = "No row is selected";
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        print json_encode($Ret)
    }     
?>
```

Then use the `$.getJson` Ajax call to retrieve the response as a Js object ([See this manual page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/))